# Move composable above visible keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My Application is fully Composable and I do not want to use View,
my objective is to show a specific Composable at the bottom of the screen, and if the keyboard appears than on top of the keyboard, is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use

```
activity?.let {               
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(it.window, false)
}
ProvideWindowInsets {
    content{}
}
```

apparently it is deprecated, here is the solution:
https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/

```
modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize().imePadding().systemBarsPadding()
```